# Damaged AIR app after signing with renewed certificate

Tags: air, code-signing

Our code-signing certificate recently expired. It's been renewed, but now whenever I try to package the app with the renewed cert (whether I attempt a migration of the expired cert or not), after installation, I get the following message any time I try to run the app:

"This installation of this application is damaged. Try re-installing or contacting the publisher for assistance."

Opening up the package contents, the publisherid file inside Resources/META-INF/AIR is blank. This is apparently the problem, because if I manually edit it to contain our previous publisherID, the app will run.

But of course, it's not like we can tell all our users "oh install it then manually edit this file inside the package."

Has anyone encountered this or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, after a bit more banging my head against my desk I got it.

For anyone who comes after me:

I had to change a couple things in my app descriptor file.

First I had to change the namespace to point at AIR 1.5.3 instead of 1.5

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/1.5.3">
```

And then I had to manually specify our old publisherID in the descriptor as well

```
<id>OurAppID</id>
<publisherID>OurOldPublisherID</publisherID>
```

Now it works just as it's supposed to, installs as an update to our old version instead of a new app, and actually runs instead of just throwing that error.